# What does copyToLocal in the hadoop environment return?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hortonworks-sandbox

I have a table in HDFS with the current path of /apps/hive/warehouse/ratings. I tried to download this to my local file system with the copyToLocal function in Hadoop.

The call worked and showed no errors, but when I go check in to the downloaded table is just a folder containing a file type.

Do you know what is the proper function call to download the table from HDFS as a CSV file?

This is the command that I am using at the moment

hadoop fs -copyToLocal /apps/hive/warehouse/ratings /home/maria_dev

[this was to check what type of file i had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPDUv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
hadoop fs -get /apps/hive/warehouse/ratings /home/maria_dev
```

And after your file is in your local file system you can rename the file to what ever you want and add your preferred file format

Comment: even after i change the format i still cant look at the file.